# Exclude posts in Wordpress Query with an external array in post__not_in

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, wordpress

I am trying to pass an array via AJAX to an external php file. It's a hard-coded list of post IDs to be excluded from the query.

This is where I'm setting the post IDs in an array, these IDs exist in the database. Then I'm passing the variable `$postsNotIn` as an imploded array to the JS file to be passed over to `ajax.php`

The problem is, it is not working. I don't think the `$postNotIn` is being passed through as an array because `post__not_in` is expecting an array.

I tried passing `$features` instead but that didn't work either.

I keep getting `0` as a response.

However when I hardcode the array in the query `'post__not_in' => array(230, 280, 268);` it works fine.

How can I pass the IDs in the correct array form to `ajax.php`?

**EDIT** if I wrap `$exclude` in `array()` like so `'post__not_in' => array($exclude)` it only excludes the first post ID while ignoring the remaining 2.

the HTML button

```
$features = array(320, 280, 268); // Array of posts to exclude
$postsNotIn = implode(", ", $features);

<a class="btn btn-lg btn-default load-more-button" 
    data-exclude="<?php echo $postsNotIn; ?>" 
    data-page="1" 
    data-url="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>">
    Load More
</a>
```

The Javascript

```
$('.load-more-button:not(.loading)').on('click', function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var ajaxurl = that.data('url');
    var page = that.data('page');
    var exclude = that.data('exclude');

    $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                page: page,
                exclude: exclude,
                action: 'load_more'
            },
            error: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
```

This is the external `ajax.php` file

```
function load_more() {
    $paged = $_POST['page'] + 1;
    $exclude = $_POST['exclude'];

    $query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'post__not_in' => $exclude
    ));

if($query->have_posts()) :
    while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
    endwhile;
else :
    echo 0;
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();

die();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`post__not_in` is expecting an array of IDs whereas you're passing in a comma-delineated string.

You need to reverse the process you ran when converting your array into a string for use in an attribute.

```
// Before using the $exclude variable, convert the string to an array
$exclude = array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $exclude ) );
```

Following our discussion in the comments section I've removed the space from the delimiter. The string being received by the AJAX callback didn't have any spaces.

I'm using `trim()` on all elements in the array to account for any IDs which did have spaces.

Comment: That didn't solve it. It's only excluding the first ID in the array.

Comment: Output the value of `$exclude` and see what your array actually looks like. It should be mirroring your original array but worth confirming before attempting any further debugging

Comment: The output of the new `$exclude` you've provided is `array (size=1)
  0 => string '320,280,268,262' (length=15)`

Comment: Answer updated. Curiously the space you were adding after the comma in your implode function (`", "`) isn't present in the string that reaches the AJAX callback. In the updated answer I'm imploding on the comma alone and trimming whitespace

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thank you. I don't understand the space after the comma, was I not supposed to add a space after it in the first place?

Comment: You're imploding with `', ' ` therefore the string in the HTML should be "320, 280, 268". The string being received didn't have any spaces so the original delimiter in `explode()` wasn't working. The whole thing became a single array element.